# knitr - running script without warnings

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to learn how to use knitr to quickly pull up interim overviews of R scripts in a readable format for an external audience.

At the moment - I am marking up my script with knitr syntax (as per below) and use the knitr functionality in RStudio to produce HTML outputs. Currently, I am using knitr only for interim outputs, and still coding on the underlying script. After knitr mark-up - I can still run the script in its entirety in the regular RStudio console, but of course get error messages when it e.g. tries to read the ''' lines. I am probably missing something fundamental / basic here - but is there a way to run knitr-marked-up scripts in RStudio without getting these error messages in regular console mode? or should I use another markdown format? please let me know any advice / pointers.

````
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
plot(cars)
```
````

This works perfect in knitr-HTML mode - but of course gives e.g. the following error in regular console mode

````
> ```{r}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> summary(cars)
     speed           dist       
 Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
 1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
 Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
 Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
 3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
 Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00  
> ```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> 
> You can also embed plots, for example:
Error: unexpected symbol in "You can"
>   
> ```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> plot(cars)
> ```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
>
````

Comment: the code ````{code}` identifies R code chunks and they have nothing to do with standard R syntax. R Studio allows you to run all code chunks without getting that errors. on the menù at the very right of your editor there is the "chunk" button, press it a menù appear. There is the option "run all"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have saved your script as a normal R-script, i.e. 'test.R'.
RStudio therefore interprets *all* code as normal R code.

Your knitr chunks are *not* normal R code.

**Solution:** Save your script as `.Rmd` for using Rmarkdown (most frequent) or `.Rnw` for Latex style knitr document.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error if there is an extra `(triple back tick) somewhere on your markdown page. the extra/unwanted triple back tick` will usually be above the code chunk for which the error is showing. When you delete it, the error goes away.